# Slash commands, Echo and Hello randomly added to my bot

Tags: discord.js

For some reason, when using/checking the available slash commands of my bot. I have an echo and hello command, that I have not coded in AT ALL, that just appears. I was wondering if there is anything I can do to remove these?
Here are my packages I am using for this project

```
 "@discordjs/builders": "^0.9.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^0.1.0-canary.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.25.2",
    "discord.js": "^13.3.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
```

Here is the interaction Creator

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({
                content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', 
                ephemeral: true 
            });
        }
    },
};
```

Here is the command handler

```
const { 
    REST 
} = require('@discordjs/rest');

const {
     Routes
} = require('discord-api-types/v9');


const fs = require('fs');
// Place your client and guild ids here
const clientId = '904224432338399243';
const guildId = '922603289898528768';


module.exports = (client) => {
    client.handleCommands = async(commandFolders, path) => {
        client.commandArray = [];
        for (folder of commandFolders) {
            const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`${path}/${folder}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

            for (const file of commandFiles) {
                const command = require(`../commands/${folder}/${file}`);
                // Set a new item in the Collection
                // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
                client.commandArray.push(command.data.toJSON());
            }
        }
        const rest = new REST({
             version: '9' 
        }).setToken(process.env.token);

        (async () => {
            try {
                console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

                await rest.put(
                    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
                        { body: client.commandArray },
                );

                console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })();
     };
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Mintels!
**Try those solutions:**

1. Registering your bot in a single guild (not globally)
2. Kicking the bot out of the guild and re-inviting it
3. Leave your code running for some time

---

Hope this helped and have a great day!

Comment: Just tried all of these, and none worked. all of them I already do. and I went I kicked the bot. it didnt register my guild at first but still had the hello and echo command

Comment: Specify more information about your code if you want to get help, edit your question and add a slash command register chunk to it

Comment: I have added 2 Extra areas to make sure I had enough. they have been specified in the post